# .dart files in the project build after upgrading to DartEditor 1.4

Tags: build, dart

After upgrading to DartEditor 1.4 files with .dart extension started to appear in the "build\web" folder.

We do fully automatic build of our product and the DART part ends up in the WAR file that is distributed to customers. Since I am reluctant to distribute the source code to customers, is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thank you,

Yuri.

Comment: I haven't seen this to happen except when I executed `pub build`.

Comment: That's when it happens. We use "pub build" for our automated build.

Comment: I do need the build output, but JS, not DART files.

Comment: Sorry, I see. I guess this is when you use `pub build --mode=debug`. Haven't done this for a while but this used to generate *.dart files as well. You shouldn't use the debug build for deployment.